# Melisma not extending when second voice has notes during it

Tags: lilypond

Having this code :

```
\version "2.19.55"
\language "italiano"

soloistsMelody = \relative do'' {
  \time 2/4
  <mi la>16 <sol re>16 <fa do>16 <sol re>16<mi la>8 <mi la>8 si4\rest
}

soloistsWords = \lyricmode {
  Por tu~in -- men -- sa glo -- ria 
}

womenMelody = \relative do' {
  \time 2/4
  <sol' si>2 (<mi la>4) si'8\rest
}

womenWords = \lyricmode {
  Ah __ 
}

\score {
  \new ChoirStaff <<

    \new Voice = "soloists" {
      \voiceOne
      \soloistsMelody
    }

    \new Lyrics = "soloistslyrics"

    \new Voice = "womenvoice" {
      \womenMelody
    }

    \new Lyrics = "womenlyrics"

    \context Lyrics = "soloistslyrics" {
      \lyricsto "soloists" {
        \soloistsWords
      }
    }

    \context Lyrics = "womenlyrics" {
      \lyricsto "womenvoice" {
        \womenWords
      }
    }
  >>

}
```

I expected to have this kind of result

[image]

(I obtained this result by deleting the soloist voice) but I have this :

[image: actual result].

As you can see, the melisma doens't go to the next note and it only happens when I have another voice singing during it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works nicely in LilyPond 2.18.2; perhaps there is a bug in the development version.

[image: 2.18 version]

Unrelated to the question asked, but you can also slim down the code in your `\score` block slightly:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "italiano"

soloistsMelody = \relative do'' {
  \time 2/4
  <mi la>16 <sol re>16 <fa do>16 <sol re>16<mi la>8 <mi la>8 si4\rest
}

soloistsWords = \lyricmode {
  Por tu~in -- men -- sa glo -- ria 
}

womenMelody = \relative do' {
  \time 2/4
  <sol' si>2 (<mi la>4) si'8\rest
}

womenWords = \lyricmode {
  Ah __ 
}

\score {
  \new ChoirStaff <<

    \new Voice = "soloists" {
      \voiceOne
      \soloistsMelody
    }

    \new Lyrics = "soloistslyrics" \lyricsto "soloists" {
      \soloistsWords
    }

    \new Voice = "womenvoice" {
      \womenMelody
    }

    \new Lyrics = "womenlyrics" \lyricsto "womenvoice" {
      \womenWords
    }
  >>

}
```

Comment: I think they patched it indeed because now it works with `2.19.58` (I needed it because in a previous question my problem was that `2.18.2` was the problem...-_-)

Answer (score 1):

You write stuff like

```
\new Lyrics = "soloistslyrics"

\new Voice = "womenvoice" {
  \womenMelody
}
```

which means to start a `lyrics` context `"soloistslyrics"` *inside* of which you start a new `Voice` `"womenvoice"` with the content `\womenMelody`.  Into this existing `Lyrics` context you later hook with `\context "soloistslyrics"` and add additional material.

However, the overall timing of `"soloistslyrics"` already contains all of the timing of `\womenMelody` even though the resulting *output* is redirected away into a `Voice` context.  Since you added additional time points to the time track of `"soloistslyrics"`, those time points end the melisma early.

You cannot write `\new Lyrics = "soloistslyrics"` without following it up with a music expression, and the `\new Voice ...` is a really bad idea for that.

Probably even `{}` would be better, but all in all you'd better rearrange your input where you don't separate context starts with context content in that manner.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! It's strange because I'm sure I did like the manual said but looking http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/techniques-specific-to-lyrics#working-with-lyrics-and-variables I understand that I forgot to add the `\new Staff {...}` around my voices, no ?